# Can not deserialize array from XML

Tags: c#, xml

To deserialize a XML file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProbeEntries xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Entries>
    <ProbeEntry>
      <FQDN>ns.foo.net</FQDN>
      <Answers>
        <string>20.7.19.1</string>
        <string>20.7.19.2</string>
      </Answers>
    </ProbeEntry>
  </Entries>
</ProbeEntries>
```

Several classes are defined as follows:

```
namespace TestXML
{
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class ProbeEntries
    {
        private ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntry[] entriesField;

        [XmlArrayAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [XmlArrayItemAttribute("ProbeEntry", typeof(ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntry), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
        public ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntry[] Entries
        {
            get
            {
                return this.entriesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.entriesField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntry
    {
        private ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers[] answersField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElementAttribute("Answers", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers[] Answers
        {
            get
            {
                return this.answersField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.answersField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers
    {
        private string stringField;

        [XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, ElementName = "string")]
        public string String
        {
            get
            {
                return this.stringField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.stringField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ProbesReader
    {
        public static ProbeEntries Read(string fileName)
        {

            FileStream readFileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            XmlSerializer serializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProbeEntries));
            // Load the object saved above by using the Deserialize function
            ProbeEntries loadedObj = (ProbeEntries)serializerObj.Deserialize(readFileStream);
            // Cleanup
            readFileStream.Close();
            return loadedObj;
        }
    }
}
```

But when reading the XML fine with ProbesReader.Read, for the  element, I expect two : one is 20.7.19.1 and another one is 20.7.19.2. But only first one is returned and second one is missing. I was wondering what is wrong with my class definition for XML file?

Comment: How does this question relate to XML?

Comment: @Fresh, Because its a question about Xml serialization

Comment: @sa_ddam213 When the writer posted their question it initially had no code pertaining to XML. It has since been updated, so now it's all good!

Comment: do both of the strings belong to 1 `ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers` or is that 2 `ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers` with one string each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes do not mach the data in the Xml, you are going to have to change a few things

First you are going to need `XmlArrayAttribute` and `XmlArrayItemAttribute` attribute on `Answers`.
The `XmlArrayItemAttribute` is going to have to be named `string` like in the xml

```
public class ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntry
{
    private ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers[] answersField;

    /// <remarks/>
   [XmlArrayAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
   [XmlArrayItemAttribute("string", typeof(ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers[] Answers
    {
        get
        {
            return this.answersField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.answersField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the `ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers` class you will have to set `XmlText` on the `String` property as it is the content of `ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers` element

```
public class ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers
{
    private string stringField;

    [XmlText]
    public string String
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stringField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.stringField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This will retun the mutiple results you need based on the xml example you provided

**Item1:**

[image]

**Item2:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

replace `ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers`

for

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers
{
    private string[] stringField;

    [XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, ElementName = "string")]
    public string[] String
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stringField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.stringField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

you need an array of string since there is more than one

Comment: That was my first impression aswell but I am not sure how this will work wne there is mutiple `ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers` in `Answers`, I am not sure if each string belongs to a seperate `ProbeEntriesEntriesProbeEntryAnswers` or if they all belong to a single one, well I guess one of us has the correct answer :)